# Python Plotly-Dash: Any way to stay in the same location when refreshed?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am creating a settings tab with callbacks to show selected inputs whenever user toggles with the buttons. However, this means that the page is refreshed with every click, and essentially scrolls all the way back to the top, which is quite annoying for a user.
 (E.g. If you click "Total WeekTurn since Launch" slider, it will refresh to top)

Is there any way to refresh in place? I do not wish to use lag or debounce features to slow down refresh as that would mean the inputs aren't reflected instantly to the user. 
 (i.e. I want the instant output of what is selected appearing above the slider, for example)

Thank you!

Minimum Example as Requested:

```
import argparse
import dash
import json
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_daq as daq
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd
import webbrowser
from dash.dependencies import Input, State, Output

# Set up the app
app = dash.Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
app.title = 'Example App'
server = app.server
app_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8050/'

# Define global variables
current_create_criteria_clicks = 0
outputs_path = 'outputs/'

# Define dropdown options
combined_criteria = []

# Define upload default text
upload_default_text = html.Div([
    'Drag and drop or ',
    html.A('select file')
])
# Define UI styles
input_area_style = {
    'width': '23%',
    'display': 'inline-block',
    'vertical-align': 'top',
    'font-family': 'Helvetica'
}
separator_area_style = {
    'width': '2%',
    'display': 'inline-block',
    'vertical-align': 'top',
    'font-family': 'Helvetica'
}
output_area_style = {
    'width': '75%',
    'display': 'inline-block',
    'vertical-align': 'top',
    'font-family': 'Helvetica'
}
left_output_area_style = {
    'width': '47%',
    'display': 'inline-block',
    'vertical-align': 'top'
}
right_output_area_style = {
    'width': '47%',
    'display': 'inline-block',
    'vertical-align': 'top',
    'font-family': 'Helvetica'
}
upload_box_style = {
    'width': '100%',
    'height': '60px',
    'lineHeight': '60px',
    'borderWidth': '1px',
    'borderStyle': 'dashed',
    'borderRadius': '10px',
    'textAlign': 'center',
    'margin': '0px',
    'font-family': 'Helvetica'
}
button_style = {
    'width': '50%',
    'height': '60px',
    'textAlign': 'center',
    'font-family': 'Helvetica'
}
center_placement_style = {
    'display': 'flex',
    'align-items': 'center',
    'justify-content': 'center',
    'font-family': 'Helvetica'
}

# Define hover_texts
text = {
    'settings-pX0-md-perc-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-TotalWeekLaunch-text':
        ['If article was launched within or equals last N defined weeks, ',
         'there will be no movement for these SKUs x Stores.'],
    'settings-pX0-minmax-TotalWeekLaunch-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-RptWeekLaunch-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-minmax-RptWeekLaunch-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-StoreCount-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-minmax-StoreCount-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-SOH-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-minmax-SOH-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-UTDSellThrough-perc-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-minmax-UTDSellThrough-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-ActualColorWeekTurnover-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-minmax-ActualColorWeekTurnover-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-TotalColorWeekTurnover-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-minmax-TotalColorWeekTurnover-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-CoreStatus-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-BrokenStatus-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-SKUGrade-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-Seasonality-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-Ideal-MD-ROS-text':
        [''],
    'settings-pX0-CombinedCriteria-text':
        ['']
}


def generate_hover_text(target_name):
    return dbc.Tooltip(
        text[target_name],
        target=target_name,
        placement='top-start',
        style={'width': '220pt',
               'line-height': '150%',
               'background-color': 'white',
               'font-family': 'Helvetica',
               'border': '2px solid #89CFF0',
               'border-radius': '5px',
               'padding-top': '5px',
               'padding-bottom': '5px',
               'padding-right': '5px',
               'padding-left': '10px'}
    )


def generate_default_settings(target_item, slider_max=50, slider_steps=1, mark_jumps=5):
    target_item_text = '-'.join(str(target_item).split('-')[:-1]) + '-text'
    target_item_area = '-'.join(str(target_item).split('-')[:-1]) + '-area'

    if 'booleanswitch' in target_item:
        display_unit = daq.BooleanSwitch(
            id=target_item,
            on=True
        )
    elif 'dropdown' in target_item:
        display_unit = dcc.Dropdown(
            id=target_item,
            multi=True
        )
    elif 'rangeslider' in target_item and ('proportion' in target_item or 'perc' in target_item):
        display_unit = dcc.RangeSlider(
            id=target_item,
            min=0,
            max=1,
            step=0.05,
            marks={value / 10: value / 10 for value in range(0, 10)}
        )
    elif 'rangeslider' in target_item:
        display_unit = dcc.RangeSlider(
            id=target_item,
            min=0,
            max=slider_max,
            step=slider_steps,
            marks={value * mark_jumps: value * mark_jumps for value in range(0, 10)}
        )
    elif ('slider' in target_item) and ('proportion' in target_item or 'perc' in target_item):
        display_unit = dcc.Slider(
            id=target_item,
            min=0,
            max=1,
            step=0.05,
            marks={value / 10: value / 10 for value in range(0, 10)}
        )
    elif 'slider' in target_item:
        display_unit = dcc.Slider(
            id=target_item,
            min=0,
            max=slider_max,
            step=slider_steps,
            marks={value * mark_jumps: value * mark_jumps for value in range(0, 10)}
        )

    return html.Div(
        id=target_item_area,
        children=[
            html.P(id=target_item_text),
            generate_hover_text(target_item_text),
            display_unit
        ]
    )


# Define app layout
app.layout = html.Div(
    id='app-body',
    children=[
        html.Div([
            html.H1('Example App')
        ], style={'text-align': 'left',
                  'margin-right': 20,
                  'display': 'inline-block',
                  'font-family': 'Helvetica'}),
        html.Div(
            id='tabs-area',
            children=[
                dcc.Tabs(
                    id='tabs',
                    children=[
                        dcc.Tab(
                            id='settings-tab',
                            label='Settings',
                            style={'font-family': 'Helvetica'},
                            children=[
                                html.Div(
                                    id='settings-output-area',
                                    children=[
                                        dcc.Loading(
                                            id='settings-output-loading',
                                            children=[
                                                html.Div(
                                                    id='left-separator-settings-output-area',
                                                    style=separator_area_style
                                                ),
                                                html.Div(
                                                    id='left-settings-output-area',
                                                    children=[],
                                                    style=left_output_area_style
                                                ),
                                                html.Div(
                                                    id='separator-settings-output-area',
                                                    style=separator_area_style
                                                ),
                                                html.Div(
                                                    id='right-settings-output-area',
                                                    children=[
                                                        html.H4('Criteria Creator'),
                                                        generate_default_settings('settings-pX0-md-perc-slider'),
                                                        generate_default_settings(
                                                            'settings-pX0-TotalWeekLaunch-slider'),
                                                        daq.BooleanSwitch(
                                                            id='settings-pX0-minmax-TotalWeekLaunch-booleanswitch'),
                                                        generate_default_settings('settings-pX0-RptWeekLaunch-slider'),
                                                        daq.BooleanSwitch(
                                                            id='settings-pX0-minmax-RptWeekLaunch-booleanswitch'),
                                                        generate_default_settings('settings-pX0-StoreCount-slider'),
                                                        daq.BooleanSwitch(
                                                            id='settings-pX0-minmax-StoreCount-booleanswitch'),
                                                        generate_default_settings(
                                                            'settings-pX0-SOH-slider',
                                                            slider_max=1000, slider_steps=5, mark_jumps=100
                                                        ),
                                                        daq.BooleanSwitch(id='settings-pX0-minmax-SOH-booleanswitch'),
                                                        generate_default_settings(
                                                            'settings-pX0-UTDSellThrough-perc-slider'),
                                                        daq.BooleanSwitch(
                                                            id='settings-pX0-minmax-UTDSellThrough-booleanswitch'),
                                                        generate_default_settings(
                                                            'settings-pX0-ActualColorWeekTurnover-slider',
                                                            slider_max=60, mark_jumps=6
                                                        ),
                                                        daq.BooleanSwitch(
                                                            id='settings-pX0-minmax-ActualColorWeekTurnover-booleanswitch'
                                                        ),
                                                        generate_default_settings(
                                                            'settings-pX0-TotalColorWeekTurnover-slider',
                                                            slider_max=60, mark_jumps=6
                                                        ),
                                                        daq.BooleanSwitch(
                                                            id='settings-pX0-minmax-TotalColorWeekTurnover-booleanswitch'
                                                        ),
                                                        generate_default_settings('settings-pX0-CoreStatus-dropdown'),
                                                        generate_default_settings('settings-pX0-BrokenStatus-dropdown'),
                                                        generate_default_settings('settings-pX0-SKUGrade-dropdown'),
                                                        generate_default_settings('settings-pX0-Seasonality-dropdown'),
                                                        generate_default_settings('settings-pX0-Ideal-MD-ROS-dropdown'),
                                                        html.Button(
                                                            id='settings-pX0-create-criteria-button',
                                                            n_clicks=0,
                                                            children='Create Criteria',
                                                            style=button_style
                                                        ),
                                                        html.Button(
                                                            id='settings-pX0-clear-criteria-button',
                                                            n_clicks=0,
                                                            children='Reset Criteria',
                                                            style=button_style
                                                        ),
                                                        html.H4('MD Criteria Selector'),
                                                        generate_default_settings(
                                                            'settings-pX0-CombinedCriteria-dropdown')
                                                    ],
                                                    style=right_output_area_style
                                                ),
                                                html.Div(
                                                    id='right-separator-settings-output-area',
                                                    style=separator_area_style
                                                )
                                            ],
                                            type='circle',
                                            style={'vertical-align': 'middle'}
                                        )
                                    ],
                                    style=output_area_style
                                ),
                                html.P(id='settings-placeholder')
                            ]
                        )
                    ]
                )
            ]
        )
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    [
        Output('settings-pX0-md-perc-text', 'children'),
        Output('settings-pX0-TotalWeekLaunch-text', 'children'),
        Output('settings-pX0-RptWeekLaunch-text', 'children'),
        Output('settings-pX0-StoreCount-text', 'children'),
        Output('settings-pX0-SOH-text', 'children'),
        Output('settings-pX0-UTDSellThrough-perc-text', 'children'),
        Output('settings-pX0-ActualColorWeekTurnover-text', 'children'),
        Output('settings-pX0-TotalColorWeekTurnover-text', 'children'),
        Output('settings-pX0-CoreStatus-text', 'children'),
        Output('settings-pX0-BrokenStatus-text', 'children'),
        Output('settings-pX0-SKUGrade-text', 'children'),
        Output('settings-pX0-Seasonality-text', 'children'),
        Output('settings-pX0-Ideal-MD-ROS-text', 'children'),
        Output('settings-pX0-CombinedCriteria-dropdown', 'options')
    ],
    [
        Input('settings-pX0-create-criteria-button', 'n_clicks'),
        Input('settings-pX0-md-perc-slider', 'value'),
        Input('settings-pX0-TotalWeekLaunch-slider', 'value'),
        Input('settings-pX0-minmax-TotalWeekLaunch-booleanswitch', 'on'),
        Input('settings-pX0-RptWeekLaunch-slider', 'value'),
        Input('settings-pX0-minmax-RptWeekLaunch-booleanswitch', 'on'),
        Input('settings-pX0-StoreCount-slider', 'value'),
        Input('settings-pX0-minmax-StoreCount-booleanswitch', 'on'),
        Input('settings-pX0-SOH-slider', 'value'),
        Input('settings-pX0-minmax-SOH-booleanswitch', 'on'),
        Input('settings-pX0-UTDSellThrough-perc-slider', 'value'),
        Input('settings-pX0-minmax-UTDSellThrough-booleanswitch', 'on'),
        Input('settings-pX0-ActualColorWeekTurnover-slider', 'value'),
        Input('settings-pX0-minmax-ActualColorWeekTurnover-booleanswitch', 'on'),
        Input('settings-pX0-TotalColorWeekTurnover-slider', 'value'),
        Input('settings-pX0-minmax-TotalColorWeekTurnover-booleanswitch', 'on'),
        Input('settings-pX0-CoreStatus-dropdown', 'value'),
        Input('settings-pX0-BrokenStatus-dropdown', 'value'),
        Input('settings-pX0-SKUGrade-dropdown', 'value'),
        Input('settings-pX0-Seasonality-dropdown', 'value'),
        Input('settings-pX0-Ideal-MD-ROS-dropdown', 'value')
    ]
)
def update_criteria_dropdown(pX0_create_criteria_clicks, pX0_md_perc, pX0_TotalWeekLaunch,
                             pX0_minmax_TotalWeekLaunch,
                             pX0_RptWeekLaunch, pX0_minmax_RptWeekLaunch, pX0_StoreCount, pX0_minmax_StoreCount,
                             pX0_SOH, pX0_minmax_SOH, pX0_UTDSellThrough, pX0_minmax_UTDSellThrough,
                             pX0_ActualColorWeekTurnover, pX0_minmax_ActualColorWeekTurnover,
                             pX0_TotalColorWeekTurnover, pX0_minmax_TotalColorWeekTurnover, pX0_CoreStatus,
                             pX0_BrokenStatus, pX0_SKUGrade, pX0_Seasonality, pX0_IdealMDROS):
    global current_create_criteria_clicks
    global combined_criteria

    pX0_md_perc_text = 'Proposed Additional MD %'
    pX0_TotalWeekLaunch_text = 'Number of Launch Weeks'
    pX0_RptWeekLaunch_text = 'Number of Rpt Launch Weeks'
    pX0_StoreCount_text = 'Number of Stores Holding'
    pX0_SOH_text = 'Total SOH Qty'
    pX0_UTDSellThrough_text = 'UTD SellThrough %'
    pX0_ActualColorWeekTurnover_text = 'Current WeekTurn'
    pX0_TotalColorWeekTurnover_text = 'Total WeekTurn since Launch'
    pX0_CoreStatus_text = 'Apply to selected Core Status'
    pX0_BrokenStatus_text = 'Apply to selected Broken Status'
    pX0_SKUGrade_text = 'Apply to selected ABC Grade'
    pX0_Seasonality_text = 'Apply to selected Seasonality'
    pX0_IdealMDROS_text = 'Apply to selected Ideal LastMD ROS Status'

    # update combined_criteria
    def tf_more_less(boo):
        return 'min >=' if boo else 'max <='
        # return 'Largest to Smallest' if boo else 'Smallest to Largest'

    criteria_dict = {}
    if pX0_md_perc is not None:
        pX0_md_perc_text += ': %d ' % (pX0_md_perc * 100) + '%'
        criteria_dict['MD_Req'] = pX0_md_perc
    if None not in (pX0_TotalWeekLaunch, pX0_minmax_TotalWeekLaunch):
        pX0_TotalWeekLaunch_text += ': ' + tf_more_less(pX0_minmax_TotalWeekLaunch) + '%d' % pX0_TotalWeekLaunch
        criteria_dict['TotalWeekLaunch'] = {}
        criteria_dict['TotalWeekLaunch']['value'] = pX0_TotalWeekLaunch
        criteria_dict['TotalWeekLaunch']['min'] = pX0_minmax_TotalWeekLaunch
    if None not in (pX0_RptWeekLaunch, pX0_minmax_RptWeekLaunch):
        pX0_RptWeekLaunch_text += ': ' + tf_more_less(pX0_minmax_RptWeekLaunch) + '%d' % pX0_RptWeekLaunch
        criteria_dict['RptWeekLaunch'] = {}
        criteria_dict['RptWeekLaunch']['value'] = pX0_RptWeekLaunch
        criteria_dict['RptWeekLaunch']['min'] = pX0_minmax_RptWeekLaunch
    if None not in (pX0_StoreCount, pX0_minmax_StoreCount):
        pX0_StoreCount_text += ': ' + tf_more_less(pX0_minmax_StoreCount) + '%d' % pX0_StoreCount
        criteria_dict['StoreCount'] = {}
        criteria_dict['StoreCount']['value'] = pX0_StoreCount
        criteria_dict['StoreCount']['min'] = pX0_minmax_StoreCount
    if None not in (pX0_SOH, pX0_minmax_SOH):
        pX0_SOH_text += ': ' + tf_more_less(pX0_minmax_SOH) + '%d' % pX0_SOH
        criteria_dict['SOH'] = {}
        criteria_dict['SOH']['value'] = pX0_SOH
        criteria_dict['SOH']['min'] = pX0_minmax_SOH
    if None not in (pX0_UTDSellThrough, pX0_minmax_UTDSellThrough):
        pX0_UTDSellThrough_text += ': ' + tf_more_less(pX0_minmax_UTDSellThrough) + '%d' % (
                    pX0_UTDSellThrough * 100) + '%'
        criteria_dict['UTDSellThrough'] = {}
        criteria_dict['UTDSellThrough']['value'] = pX0_UTDSellThrough
        criteria_dict['UTDSellThrough']['min'] = pX0_minmax_UTDSellThrough
    if None not in (pX0_ActualColorWeekTurnover, pX0_minmax_ActualColorWeekTurnover):
        pX0_ActualColorWeekTurnover_text += ': ' + tf_more_less(
            pX0_minmax_ActualColorWeekTurnover) + '%d' % pX0_ActualColorWeekTurnover
        criteria_dict['ActualColorWeekTurnover'] = {}
        criteria_dict['ActualColorWeekTurnover']['value'] = pX0_ActualColorWeekTurnover
        criteria_dict['ActualColorWeekTurnover']['min'] = pX0_minmax_ActualColorWeekTurnover
    if None not in (pX0_TotalColorWeekTurnover, pX0_minmax_TotalColorWeekTurnover):
        pX0_TotalColorWeekTurnover_text += ': ' + tf_more_less(
            pX0_minmax_TotalColorWeekTurnover) + '%d' % pX0_TotalColorWeekTurnover
        criteria_dict['TotalColorWeekTurnover'] = {}
        criteria_dict['TotalColorWeekTurnover']['value'] = pX0_TotalColorWeekTurnover
        criteria_dict['TotalColorWeekTurnover']['min'] = pX0_minmax_TotalColorWeekTurnover
    if pX0_CoreStatus is not None:
        if len(pX0_CoreStatus) > 0:
            criteria_dict['CoreStatus'] = pX0_CoreStatus
    if pX0_BrokenStatus is not None:
        if len(pX0_BrokenStatus) > 0:
            criteria_dict['BrokenStatus'] = pX0_BrokenStatus
    if pX0_SKUGrade is not None:
        if len(pX0_SKUGrade) > 0:
            criteria_dict['SKUGrade'] = pX0_SKUGrade
    if pX0_Seasonality is not None:
        if len(pX0_Seasonality) > 0:
            criteria_dict['Seasonality'] = pX0_Seasonality
    if pX0_IdealMDROS is not None:
        if len(pX0_IdealMDROS) > 0:
            criteria_dict['LastMDROSStatus'] = pX0_IdealMDROS

    if pX0_create_criteria_clicks is not None and pX0_create_criteria_clicks > 0 \
            and pX0_create_criteria_clicks > current_create_criteria_clicks \
            and 'MD_Req' in criteria_dict.keys() and len(criteria_dict) > 1:
        current_create_criteria_clicks = pX0_create_criteria_clicks
        combined_criteria.append(json.dumps(criteria_dict))

    crits = [{'label': crit, 'value': crit} for crit in combined_criteria]

    return pX0_md_perc_text, pX0_TotalWeekLaunch_text, pX0_RptWeekLaunch_text, pX0_StoreCount_text, pX0_SOH_text, \
           pX0_UTDSellThrough_text, pX0_ActualColorWeekTurnover_text, pX0_TotalColorWeekTurnover_text, \
           pX0_CoreStatus_text, pX0_BrokenStatus_text, pX0_SKUGrade_text, pX0_Seasonality_text, pX0_IdealMDROS_text, crits

@app.callback(
    [
        Output('settings-pX0-md-perc-slider', 'value'),
        Output('settings-pX0-TotalWeekLaunch-slider', 'value'),
        Output('settings-pX0-minmax-TotalWeekLaunch-booleanswitch', 'on'),
        Output('settings-pX0-RptWeekLaunch-slider', 'value'),
        Output('settings-pX0-minmax-RptWeekLaunch-booleanswitch', 'on'),
        Output('settings-pX0-StoreCount-slider', 'value'),
        Output('settings-pX0-minmax-StoreCount-booleanswitch', 'on'),
        Output('settings-pX0-SOH-slider', 'value'),
        Output('settings-pX0-minmax-SOH-booleanswitch', 'on'),
        Output('settings-pX0-UTDSellThrough-perc-slider', 'value'),
        Output('settings-pX0-minmax-UTDSellThrough-booleanswitch', 'on'),
        Output('settings-pX0-ActualColorWeekTurnover-slider', 'value'),
        Output('settings-pX0-minmax-ActualColorWeekTurnover-booleanswitch', 'on'),
        Output('settings-pX0-TotalColorWeekTurnover-slider', 'value'),
        Output('settings-pX0-minmax-TotalColorWeekTurnover-booleanswitch', 'on'),
        Output('settings-pX0-CoreStatus-dropdown', 'value'),
        Output('settings-pX0-BrokenStatus-dropdown', 'value'),
        Output('settings-pX0-SKUGrade-dropdown', 'value'),
        Output('settings-pX0-Seasonality-dropdown', 'value'),
        Output('settings-pX0-Ideal-MD-ROS-dropdown', 'value')
    ],
    [
        Input('settings-pX0-clear-criteria-button', 'n_clicks')
    ]
)
def clear_criteria(clear_criteria_clicks):
    return None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, \
           [], [], [], [], []



# Run the Dash app server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example App')
    parser.add_argument('--debug', help='Run the app in debug mode', action='store_true')
    arguments = parser.parse_args()
    webbrowser.open(app_url)
    # Run the Dash server
    app.run_server(debug=arguments.debug)
```

Comment: Please post you r code (layout and callbacks) so we can understand the context

Comment: @A.B just added! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [dcc.tabs](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/tabs) example from official documentation. This will help you to avoid refresh on changing the tab.

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Tabs(id='tabs-example', value='tab-1', children=[
        dcc.Tab(label='Tab one', value='tab-1'),
        dcc.Tab(label='Tab two', value='tab-2'),
    ]),
    html.Div(id='tabs-example-content')
])

@app.callback(Output('tabs-example-content', 'children'),
              [Input('tabs-example', 'value')])
def render_content(tab):
    if tab == 'tab-1':
        return html.Div([
            html.H3('Tab content 1')
        ])
    elif tab == 'tab-2':
        return html.Div([
            html.H3('Tab content 2')
        ])
```

you can extend the idea further by storing content of the tab separately like, or event import it from different file

```
   tab1_layout = [ html.Div([ dcc.Graph … etc ]) ]
   tab2_content = [ html.Div([ dcc.Graph … etc ]) ]
```

Comment: hi, I just added a minimum example. My problem isn't about changing tabs, but rather within each tab, it is refreshing to top.